# How to include Jsonschema multiple type parameter with enum?

Tags: python, enums, jsonschema

By the below example question will get more clear:

```
data = {"type": "object", "properties": {"product": {"type": ["boolean","string"]}}}
```

It includes both `boolean` and `string` types. It works, but I want to limit the string part to a list of `enums`:

```
["off", "on", "semi-on"]
```

When `type` is not a `list` it works, but when I make it as a list then I cannot provide the `enum` for the `string` type.

The below example without `boolean` works too:

```
data = {"type": "object", "properties": {"product": {"type": "string", "enum": ["off", "on", "semi-on"]}}}
```

Should split the schema, or is there another way for this?

---

**EDIT-1:** The real schema is as below:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "is_trusted": {"type": "boolean"},
        "is_active": {"type": "boolean"},
        "addresses": {"type": "array"},
        "attachments": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "send_web_push": {"type": "boolean"},
                "receive_web_push": {"type": "boolean"}
            },
            "required": ["send_web_push", "receive_web_push"],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "required": ["is_trusted", "is_active", "addresses"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: The way you've presented looks reasonable. I'm going to need some more information to help though. Can you let me know what version of JSON Schema you are using please (The draft number)? Thanks.

Comment: Also please provide the full JSON instance you want to validate with your schema. This will help me make sure there isn't some other problem which means your schema is passing validation when you don't believe it should.

Comment: @Relequestual Thank you for your comment, please have a look at the `EDIT-1` section.

Comment: I can't see `enum` in your schema. I'm also going to assume you are using draft 7, and I will now answer your question.

Comment: @Relequestual well the question(problem) is that I cannot use enum when multiple types are set. I couldn't handle it using `jsonschema`.

Comment: Right, you were using it incorrectly, but I would still have liked to have seen where you thought it should go, so I could show you the fixed version, with a valid instance.

Comment: Feel free to join the JSON Schema slack should you have any issues which don't fit into a SO question. "Discussion" link on the JSON Schema site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON Schema defines validation keywords sectioned by how they will apply to an instance.

`enum` is under the [Validation Keywords for Any Instance Type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.1) section.

This means it is applicable to any instance type, including booleans.

As such, you must include the boolean values `true` and `false` in your enum of valid values. (This does make `type` redundant in this example).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "product": {
      "type": [
        "boolean",
        "string"
      ],
      "enum": [
        "off",
        "on",
        "semi-on",
        true,
        false
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The below instance is now valid for the above schema.
In your first schema, `product` having a value of `true` would fail `enum` validation because `true` is not included in the enum.

```
{
  "product": true
}
```